# Using htmlparse to replace image and css source urls in a html file (python)

Tags: python, html-parsing

I'm trying to write a script that will download a webpage, including all the images and style sheets - i.e. so a locally hosted version looks identical to the original.

Originally I was just downloading the images, but I realize now that I have to (of course) edit the html source so that the img src actually points to the locally hosted image. As I have to change the html source anyway, I decided it was better if I just updated the locally hosted file to point to the images and style sheets hosted remotely.

So this brings me to my question, can I use htmlparse to search for the style sheets and image tags and then replace the links to them with the updated versions?

I've had a look at the htmlparse documentation, but I'm still pretty new to python so some parts unclear. I thought it might be possible to use:

```
HTMLParser.handle_data(data)
This method is called to process arbitrary data. It is intended to be overridden by a 
derived class; the base class implementation does nothing.
```

and add my own replacing class to it? Or am I on totally the wrong lines?

Another option of course would be to use regular expressions to search for the tags and replace the text after them, but this could get pretty complicated so I was wondering if htmlparse would provide a simpler solution.

I realize that beautiful soup would be the ideal solution, but I will be distributing the finished tool around my company, so I can't use any third party modules unfortunately. Similarly I'd like the tool to be platform independent, so unfortunately cannot use wget.

Thanks for any input =)

Comment: I believe `wget -H -k -p` will do what you want -- no need to code this yourself. (See the [relevant section of the `wget` documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Retrieval-Options.html#index-page-requisites-127)).

Comment: I wish I could use wget, it'd make life so much easier - unfortunately I wan't this tool to be platform independent as well. Sorry I should have mentioned that in the original post, I'll edit it as such - cheers for your suggestion though =)

Comment: As far as I am aware, `wget` runs on Windows, Linux, Mac and almost any other UNIX-like platform.

Comment: If you really want to code this yourself, parsing the HTML page is not enough -- you also need to download and parse all embedded and external style sheets of the page.

Comment: that's true, though it's not native to windows - if I can't find anything else that works easily, then wget will be my best option I think. Thanks!

Comment: Ah just saw your second comment. I didn't realize I'd have to further parse the downloaded style sheets - I wasn't even planning on downloading them, I thought simply appropriately updating the locally hosted source's links to the style sheets would suffice

Comment: Style sheets can contain `background-image` and `@import` directives, so you need to parse them to be able to download all page requisites.  You also need to rewrite the links in the style sheets.  Python does not include a CSS parser, so you have to include one with your script.

Comment: Ok, in that case I am just better off editing the original source of the html, just so it points to the remotely hosted files - so I don't have to bother with downloading all the style sheets etc. This brings be back to my original question though really, unless I use wget of course.

Comment: Even when just rewriting the links in the original document, you still need to parse all embedded style sheets and rewrite the links occuring there.  You still need to embed a CSS parser in your script.

Comment: Ah right ok I see, thank you. I was just planning on using htmlparse to parse for css links as well, though that looks increasingly harder =/ - perhaps just using wget to retrieve it really is the best option.

Comment: After looking into it further I decided using wget was the best option. Thanks a lot Sven!

Comment: Glad to help.  I hope it won't be too much pain to deploy wget to the Windows machines.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use any modules to your heart's content if you pack the Python program to self-contained binary (not even Python runtime necessary) with this: http://www.pyinstaller.org/